# Maintaning isolation between modules in Django monolith

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, django, boundaries, monorepo

In our company we have a monolith. Right now is not that big but we are already seeing some problems with the isolation between the modules we have. Our setup is pretty similar to other Django backends: we have a common User model and another UserProfile model where we store additional information about the user. As an additional thing, we also have a company model to group our users by company.

These models are shared across all the modules, at least they are coupled as foreign keys in the models of the rest of the modules. They are contained in a `companies` module, where we have our business rules about how many users a company can have, invariants in their profile, etc. I think this is fine because we usually just do simple and fast join by user ID or filter by it, so we treat this dependency as read-only so we don't skip any business rules/boundaries related to the companies module.

My problem comes when, for instance, some `moduleA`, needs to trigger an application service in `moduleB`. For instance, let's say `moduleB` needs to access a resource in `moduleA`. The code would be something like:

```py
# The GetResourceInterface is defined in module A!
from moduleA import GetResourceInterface

class AServiceInModuleB:
    # We use dependency injection
    
    def __init__(service: GetResourceInterface):
        pass
```

Now this is a direct import from a different module, so it seems we are breaking the boundaries (even though is not the domain layer, is just the application layer). Nonetheless, sometimes we don't return DTOs from services because our domain objects are not that big or complex to define DTOs (we would just be duplicating a class with a different name but almost the same attributes). So in those cases, we would indeed be breaking the isolation.

A possible alternative we have thought about is to contact other modules using their REST API (we define an API for every module because we also use it in our clients). In that case, the code would be something like:

```py
# The name could be different (not sure which for now)
from dependencies import ModuleAConnectorInterface

class AServiceInModuleB:
    def __init__(connector: ModuleAConnectorInterface):
         pass
```

The main advantage I think here is that the dependencies between modules are way more explicit to read in the file structure and in the code. Also, if more operations are needed from `moduleA`, they can be added to that connector too.

What possible problems do we see in this approach? The additional overhead of an additional HTTP request. This would be authenticated with JWT because that's pretty easy and fast to verify. The HTTP request would possibly just be made locally because even though we have a monolith, we have around 10 or 15 replicas of the Django app running the web server. Also, we had a bit of a worry about having a chatty architecture, where every service makes a lot of calls to other services, but honestly, this is a minor concern because we don't see it as a real thing happening with our current/future requirements.

So, my question is, is this a valid solution? Are we totally overengineering this isolation of boundaries? Our main concern is that we come from a messy monolith with no boundaries, and now we are remaking the app and the team is growing. For the sake of simplicity, we are keeping a mono-repository with our monolith, but every team is going to own a couple of modules, so we want to avoid interdependencies/breaking other people's code/stopping other people from refactoring/etc.

Sorry for the long text and let me know if you need any additional information to answer the question! Thanks! :D

Note: not sure if useful, we are using DDD, so we try to define clear bounded contexts with different domains and isolated data structures to represent the domain.